# ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers don't appear to be working in published exe

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Web API project using ASP.NET Core Identity (so it also serves up some Razor pages). These pages have script helpers, specifically `asp-append-version` and `asp-src-include`.

When running in development, these work correctly. However, in a published application (both running directly from the EXE and in IIS) the tag helpers appear to have no effect. The applicable section of code below:

```
    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Identity/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj">
        </script>
        <script src="~/Identity/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <script type="module" asp-src-include="/js/header/polyfills.*.js"></script>
    <script type="module" asp-src-include="/js/header/main.*.js"></script>
```

When running with the debugger, site.js has the version query string and it fetches the script files from the `asp-src-include` but after publishing site.js has no query string and no additional JS files are fetched.

I have tried:

- Manually putting the TagHelpers assembly in the publish directory
- Adding the @addTagHelper command to the top of the .cshtml file (instead of relying on _ViewImports)

How do I get the tag helpers to work in the published app?

For a full repository that shows this behavior, please look at https://github.com/bradley-dotnet/bug-reproduction

Comment: Hi @BradleyDotNET, Have you tried run your application on IIS Express? Does it still work fine?

Comment: Is that different than just running with the debugger? @Rena

Comment: Hi @BradleyDotNET, it works on my side. So I need check your local actually works fine. Pls check if it works fine when run on IIS Express.

Comment: @Rena Can you clarify what you mean by "IIS Express"? My understanding is that's exactly what is run by hitting the debug button. You don't deploy to it.

Comment: Hi @BrandleyDotNet, when you debug the code you can choose run on Kestrel or IIS Express. IIS Express simulates IIS to the greatest extent, avoiding developers from publishing applications to IIS every time they test, that is why I want to know if you actually works fine on IIS Express.

Comment: yes, works in debugging with IIS express @Rena

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I'm having the same issue. It works in debug/release but not in a published version.

Comment: It's been a bit since I worked on that; but I believe I never found a good solution; other than just removing build hashes from the output so it didn't matter that it wouldn't work @E.Peter